# How can hide or show text boxes based on Parameters in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

i have 4 text boxes based on different Parameters , But customer wants ,when they Preview the report just showed ,the 2 first text box which is **"Work Start Date From - Work Start Date to"** AND then make the, 2 another text box as link ,under the first text boxes AND , when they Click on the links show the, 2 another text boxes ,which is **"Work End Date From - Work End Date To"** then, make the another one as link which is "Work Start Date From - Work Start Date to" Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: As far as I know, the ReportViewer of reporting services does not offer a functionality like that. You can either show all the parameters or none.

Comment: tnx for your comment, i'm agree with you and i also searched for it ,but nothing find.